# Getting an error while creating a Java EE Web Project in Jboss Developer Studio

Tags: jboss, maven-3

I have installed the JBoss developer Studio 7.1 and trying to create a Java EE Web project. On the bottom of the page it gives a warning that
 "This project has a dependency on org.jboss.bom:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:1.0.4.final-redhat-4, which cannot be found. This indicates you do not have access to the proper Maven repository or that repository is incomplete. This can cause build problems. This can be fixed by adding the recommended repository in your settings.xml".

I have followed the link to the recommended repository and updated my settings.xml accordingly. But still when I click on finish creating the project, I get the error,

"Could not resolve archetype org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype:7.1.3.final from any of the configured repositories. Root cause: Could not resolve artifact org.jboss.spec.archetypes:jboss-javaee6-webapp-archetype:pom:7.1.3.final"

I am a novice in Jboss and Maven. Still in the process of understanding these technologies. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try to reset/refresh maven repository

## Unix - clean up

```
find ~/.m2 -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer" {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
```

## Windows - clean up

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried various things and could not create a web EE project from the Jboss Studio. So finally this is the work around that worked for me. I created the maven project separately and imported that into the Jboss development studio. Please refer to the following document for the procedure to create a project in Maven and subsequent importing.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Web_Framework_Kit/2.2/html/Maven_Repository_User_Guide/archetypes.html